# angular2 testing: add latency to mock http backend

Tags: unit-testing, http, angular, mocking

I have a service that gets data from two different backends (database over http request and live data over socket.io) and then publishes this data as a single stream. When testing this service, I would like to be able to control the delay of the mock http service, so that I can play through different kinds of racing conditions. Currently I'm doing this:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [
            DataService,
            {
                provide: IoService,
                useClass: MockIoService
            },
            {
                provide: Http,
                useFactory: (mockBackend, options) => {
                    return new Http(mockBackend, options);
                },
                deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
            },
            MockBackend,
            BaseRequestOptions
        ]
    });
});

it('should get data from http backend', async(inject([DataService, MockBackend, IoService], (service: DataService, mockBackend, ioService) => {
    const mockResponse = {
        data: [
            { id: 0, text: 'httpData', start: 0, stop: 1 }
        ]
    };
    mockBackend.connections.subscribe((connection) => {
        connection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({
            body: JSON.stringify(mockResponse)
        })));
    });
    service.subscribe('test').subscribe((data) => {
        expect(data.text).toBe('httpData');
    });
})));
```

This works but again, I would like to be able to define a delay for the `MockBackend` so that the response comes after a fixed number of seconds. Is that possible and if yes, how?